# Only accept rows without duplicate ID's

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get information out of one table which connects to another, but I only want the rows that don't have duplicate data. It's hard to explain so here's an example:

```
  table1
----------    
id    | data1 |  data2
1     |   x   |    x 
2     |   x   |    x 
3     |   x   |    x  
4     |   x   |    x  


 table2 
----------
id  | table1_id | data1 
1   |    1      |   x
2   |    2      |   x  
3   |    2      |   x  
4   |    3      |   x
```

In this case I want the get rows 1 and 4 from table 2, and not rows 2 and 3 because the table id is repeated

Comment: Is your column name literally `table1.id`?

Comment: No it would be table1_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the first table for this. Just use

```
select table1_id
from table2
group by table1_id
having count(*) < 2
```

to get the `table1_id`. If you need the complete row you can use

```
select * from table2
where table1_id in
(
    select table1_id
    from table2
    group by table1_id
    having count(*) < 2
)
```

In Mysql you could instead do

```
select *
from table2
group by table1_id
having count(*) < 2
```

but this featue is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly! Can't believe I forgot about group by.